# fork/exec/waitpid issue

Tags: c, exec, fork, execvp, waitpid

I'm trying to determine whether an execution failed by checking the result of waitpid(). However, even when I run a command that I know fails and writes the issue to stderr, the check below never registers. What could possibly be wrong with this code?

Thanks for any help.

```
pid_t pid;  // the child process that the execution runs inside of.
int ret;      // exit status of child process.

child = fork();

if (pid == -1)
{
   // issue with forking
}
else if (pid == 0)
{
   execvp(thingToRun, ThingToRunArray); // thingToRun is the program name, ThingToRunArray is
                                        //    programName + input params to it + NULL.

   exit(-1);
}
else // We're in the parent process.
{
   if (waitpid(pid, &ret, 0) == -1)
   {
      // Log an error.
   }

   if (!WIFEXITED(ret)) // If there was an error with the child process.
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: `WIFEXITED` is used to distinguish `WIFSIGNALED` and `WIFSTOPPED`.  In normal situations,  `WIFEXITED` is true when the child fails (exits with a non-zero status).  You need to check both `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`waitpid` only returns -1 if an error occurs with `waitpid`.  That is, if you give it an incorrect pid, or it is interrupted, etc.  If the child has a failing exit status, waitpid will succeed (return the pid) and set `ret` to reflect the status of the child.

To determine the status of the child, use `WIFEXITED(ret)` and `WEXITSTATUS(ret)`.  For example:

```
if( waitpid( pid, &ret, 0 ) == -1 ) {
  perror( "waitpid" );
} else if( WIFEXITED( ret ) && WEXITSTATUS( ret ) != 0 ) {
    ; /* The child failed! */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. For the first time it actually picked up an execution that was unsuccessful -- however, it now appears to consider all executions as unsuccessful... If I don't care exactly what the reason for child process failure is, shouldn't the addition code in my first updated first post be all that's needed?